# Ecto: How to use find_or_create?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a `Chat` table with `party1` and `party2` attributes which references a `User`.

When a `User` registers, a `Chat` is created between him and the existing users, so that if there are 2 users and `User 3` registers then there will be 3 chats to connect them. If `User 4` registers then there will be 6 Chats and so on.

So when `User 5` registers, Ecto will find the Chats or create them if they don't exist

```
{:ok, user, conn} ->
  id = user.id 
  less = id - 1

  if id != 1 do
    for x <- 1..less do 
      q = from c in Chat, where: (c.party1_id == ^x and c.party2_id == ^id) 
      chatmate = Repo.one(q)
      if is_nil(chatmate), do: Chats.create_chat(%{party1_id: x, party2_id: id})
    end
  end
```

Is this a case for using `find_or_create`? If so, is done like below?

```
Chat.find_or_create(c.party1_id == ^x and c.party2_id == ^id)
```

Comment: This is a very strange situation. Every registered user is in 1 giant Chat? Why do you even need to store the "party1/party2" entry?

Comment: _Sidenote:_ `for` comprehension allows filtering, `if/2` is redundant there: `for x <- 1..(user.id - 1), x > 0, do: …`.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the definition of `Chat.find_or_create`, or just test it. This isn't auto generate by phoenix in my opinion.

By the way, if the `Chat` is between two users, you can first sort the user_id, to avoid duplicate Chats. Such as:

```
[party1_id, party2_id] = Enum.sort([x, id])
```